# Is it possible to get all the offers made by a facebook page

Tags: facebook, http, rest, facebook-graph-api, request

I am currently using `https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}` and `https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/albums` and some other rest requests.

Is it possible, and if it is, how do i get all the offers made by a page.

Im not using a facebook app to do the requests so i cant use anything that requires permissions.

i could use `https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/offers?limit=5` but this needs an access token.

**EDIT**

I guess i would just have to create an application on facebook and ask the users for permission, take that access token to show them my pages offers.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, with FB ads I have no experience, however, I will provide you with some insight.

Go and use FQL, through "web syntax".

```
api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select thing, thingA, thinkB from offer where key=''value&format=json
```

Check out [`official OFFER reference`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/offer)

Comment: selecting from the offers table requires an access token.